# wildmode and wildmenu settings in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, default-settings

I'm using FreeBSD. I know that it's possible to set wildmode and wildmenu in vim using set commands. How can I do similar stuff in a Linux shell? That is, what is the settings file's name?

What I want is for the shell to display possible filenames when I type in half of of a filename and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Also, I would like to remove the annoying beep that occurs when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: It is running CShell right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD is not Linux.

To enable file and command completion add the following line to your `~/.csh` file:

```
set filec
```

Then when you type part of a command name or filename at a shell prompt you can press escape and it will complete it for you.

You can inhibit the bell by adding this line:

```
set nobeep
```

See `man csh` for more information.